# Make use of makebox in custom environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments

I am working on a custom environment, that might get larger as `\textwidth` (so `\centering` won't work), but should nevertheless be centered. I'm currently manually wrapping it with `\makebox` but would prefer including this in the environment definition. Is there any way to do it, or achieve something similar?

```
\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  %start
}{%
  %end
}
%use \makebox manually to center environment
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
  \begin{myenv}
    %some content here
  \end{myenv}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple-minded implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% <-- for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}%              <-- for the example
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\newlength\myenvlen
\newenvironment{myenv}[2][\textwidth]%
  {%
    \setlength\myenvlen{#2}%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-#2}{-#2}%
      \centering
      \begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr #1 + 2\myenvlen\relax}%
  }%
  {\end{varwidth}%
   \end{adjustwidth}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{myenv}{1cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}[.8\textwidth]{0pt}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}{5em}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myenv}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Refinements are possible, but the basic idea is that the first optional argument is when you want to have smaller-than-`\textwidth` environments, while the second argument is the value (on each side of the body) by which you want to increase environment.  If the environment would normally be smaller than `\textwidth`, you probably want to switch which one is optional and which one mandatory.

Comment: Glad it works for you!

Answer (score 4):

If you are just trying to have an environment where you can pass the contents to `\makebox` you can use the `environ` package which provides the contents of the environment in the `\BODY` macro. If the text can possibly get larger than `\textwidth` then you need to use a `\parbox` as in the `myenvPar` environment below.

But, you can also use `\centering` as the `CenteredEnvironment` (for short text)  and `CenteredEnvironmentPar` (if there is a possibility of long text) environments in the MWE:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.
- The `CenteredEnvironment` and `CenteredEnvironmentPar` do not require the `environ` package.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand*{\Text}{%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con- sectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adip- iscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
}

\NewEnviron{myenv}{%
  \noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\BODY}%
}

\newenvironment{CenteredEnvironment}{%
    \centering\noindent\ignorespaces%
}{%
    \par%
}

\NewEnviron{myenvPar}[2]{%
    \centering\noindent\parbox{#1}{\ignorespaces#2}\par%
}


\newcommand{\SavedSize}{}
\newcommand{\SavedText}{}
\newenvironment{CenteredEnvironmentPar}[2]{%
    \def\SavedSize{#1}%
    \def\SavedText{#2}%
}{%
    \centering\noindent\ignorespaces\parbox{\SavedSize}{\SavedText}\par%
}




\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}%
    some centered content here
\end{myenv}

\begin{CenteredEnvironment}
    some centered content here
\end{CenteredEnvironment}

\bigskip 
\begin{myenvPar}{6.0cm}
    \Text
\end{myenvPar}

\medskip
\begin{CenteredEnvironmentPar}{6.0cm}
    \Text
\end{CenteredEnvironmentPar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the environment needs to be centered, not the text in the environment.  Also, won't (say) putting `\lipsum[1]` in your `myenv` environment make a one-line box?  I think the goal is create an evironment than can get "larger [than] `\textwidth`", but in such a way that it is centered on the page with respect to the textblock.

Comment: @jon: I though the OP meant _as large as_ `\textwidth`. But have revised solution to also allow for longer text.

Comment: Yeah, "get larger as `\textwidth` is not entirely clear...  Anyway, interesting solution(s).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `tcolorbox` solution. This is highly customisable in the sense that you can add frame, background colours, breakable across pages etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% <-- for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}%              <-- for the example
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{myenv}[2][]{
  boxrule = 0pt,
  colback=white,
  grow to left by=#2,
  grow to right by=#2,
  left=1.6pt,
  right=1.6pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  %center upper,  %% if you want content to be centered too
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{myenv}{1cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}{-1cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}{15pt}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{myenv}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]